# How to Fade In a notification by clicking a text field

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Hi guys I need help (again). I wanted to learn how to make the notification or alert box fade-in and fade-out after clicking a editable textbox.

This is the code for the alert box:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" style="text-decoration:none">&times;</a>
    Alert: Please don't do this.
</div>
```

and this is the script for onClick:

```
function clicks() {
    document.getElementById("notif").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

I was thinking I will put the `div alert box` inside a `condition` or just a script with onClick function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example on CodePen: http://codepen.io/oculusriff/pen/aBoKvE

HTML

```
<div id="alert" class="alert alert-warning fade">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
    Alert: Please don't do this.
</div>

<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
```

JS

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('txt');
var alert = document.getElementById('alert');

txt.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  alert.classList.add('in');

  setTimeout(function() {
    alert.classList.remove('in');
  }, 2000);
});

txt.addEventListener('blur',function (){
  alert.classList.remove('in')
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I can't make it work :D should I insert your code inside my onClick function?

Comment: I've just updated my example (and the CodePen) to use the older type of JavaScript. My example was using ES6 which would probably explain why it didn't work for you. Copy and paste the code again and let me know if it works!

Comment: Also, no, you don't need to put the code inside an onClick function. It can just live by itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using CSS approach to the animation. i.e. on click add/remove a class and let css handle the animation.

However if you want to use a JavaScript solution , here is one that does not change your code much

```js
var myclickHandler = function() {
 // first show the alert
  $('.alert').show().fadeTo(500, 1);
  
  // Now set a timeout to hide it
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }, 3000);
}

// start with the alert hidden
$('.alert').hide();
$('#myTextBox').on('click', myclickHandler)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-warning fade in">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" style="text-decoration:none">&times;</a> Alert: Please don't do this.
</div>
<input id="myTextBox" type="text" value="Click here">
```

Comment: Given that Jane Doe is using Bootstrap, I think your answer this a bad approach because bootstrap has the built in classes `fade` & `in` to handle the animation. Rather than handling the animation with javascript by using `fadeTo`, it's easier to just toggle the `in` class which is what I'm doing in my answer.

Comment: @Splurtcake I agree. And hence the caveat at the beginning "I would recommend using CSS approach to the animation. i.e. on click add/remove a class and let css handle the animation."

Comment: Thank you for your help guys